# Partitioning different types of terms during parsing

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I have two parsers for different types of terms.

```
a :: Parser A
b :: Parser B
```

I have a data type representing sequences of these terms.

```
data C = C [A] [B]
```

If my input is a sequence of *mixed* terms, what’s a good way of writing `c :: Parser C` to separate the `A`s from the `B`s, preserving their order? For example, given these definitions:

```
data A = A Char
data B = B Char
a = A <$> oneOf "Aa"
b = B <$> oneOf "Bb"
```

`"abAbBBA"` would parse to the sequences `aAA` and `bbBB`. I have a feeling I need to use `StateT`, but am unsure of the specifics and just need a push in the right direction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple solution is to first parse it to a list of `Either A B` and then use [`partitionEithers`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Either.html#v:partitionEithers) to split this into two lists which you then apply the `C` constructor to.

```
c :: Parser C
c = uncurry C . partitionEithers <$> many ((Left <$> a) <|> (Right <$> b))
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much. I was definitely overcomplicating it in my mind.

Answer (score 4):

To solve your problem I'd use partitionEithers from Data.Either, the code is unchecked but it shouldn't be far off...

```
c :: Parser C
c = (post . partitionEithers ) <$> many1 aORb
  where
    post (as,bs) = C as bs


aORb :: Parser (Either A B)
aORb = (Left <$> a) <|> (Right <$> b)
```

Edit -

> Snap!